# Como criar um AuthorizeAttribute customizado no ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, .net-core, authorization

Preciso que somente alguns poucos endpoints da minha API usem um token diferente, porque eles vão ser chamados por uma aplicação menos segura e não quero que esse outro token tenha acesso a toda aplicação igual ao token padrão que o *Identity* gera para usar nos endpoints com o `[Authorize]`.
Até agora o que fiz foi:
 - Gerar manualmente um token com um algoritmo que eu criei
 - Retornar esse token através de um endpoint seguro somente para usuários `[Authorize]`

Agora para autorizar os endpoints eu tenho que fazer a validação também manualmente, resgatando do banco e comparando o token que recebi, mas eu gostaria que essa parte pudesse pelo menos usar um `[decorator]` também.
 - Tentei [sobrescrever o `AuthorizeAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493873/how-to-implement-custom-authorize-attribute-for-the-following-case), mas isso não é mais possível no .net core
 - Tentei [criar uma *policy*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) e chamar `[Authorize(Policy = "NovoToken")]`, mas antes de chamar a validação da policy já retornava `Unauthorized` porque não tinha o token do identity.
 - E por último tentei [implementar um `IAuthorizationFilter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/747891). Isso até funcionou, mas pra ele funcionar eu preciso usar o `[AllowAnonymous]` junto e fica feio ter que colocar esses dois decorator.

Finalmente **minhas perguntas são**:
 **1.** **Tem uma maneira melhor de criar um decorator** que não vai cair na validação padrão do Identity e deixar eu fazer só a minha validação?
 **2.** Ou **teria como usar o próprio Identity pra criar e validar um token alternativo**, mas deixando ele com permissão para endpoints específicos da API?

Comment: Entendo que fica estranho usar o [AllowAnonymous] já que está utilizando o [Authorize(Policy = "NovoToken")], mas desde que esteja bem documentado a solução é bem simples. O próprio nome da Policy já pode ser algo que indique a customização. Você achou alguma outra forma de fazer?

Comment: Não achei outra solução, mas depois disso não pesquisei mais. Eu vi que tem a autorização por `Authorization Code Grant`, talvez usando isso eu consiga resolver meu problema.

Comment: Olá, tive um problema semelhante. Resolvi desta forma.
https://github.com/renatogroffe/ASPNETCore2_CRUD-API-JWT-EFInMemory